# How to deploy Angular8 app in a standalone pc with the code hidden

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb, mean-stack

I have two questions a bit theoretical. I searched in the Internet but I didn't get a clear answer.

**My first question:**

I would like to develop an app in MEAN stack (Mongo, Angular8, NodeJS server), but I don't want to have a central server connected with the database somewhere and all the clients just connect to it remotely. I want to deploy the whole app (mongo database, server back-end, angular front-end) locally in a standalone pc. Yes, the user would have to activate both database and server services and yes, he would have to use the app through the browser at the *localhost* address, but I don't want him to be able to see the code. Is it possible or do you have in mind any trick to achieve that?

**My second question:**

Can I directly link mongo database with the Angular8 code without interfere the NodeJS API's?

I know that my questions are a bit generic, but I am not looking for huge answers, rather if my questions are possible and some tips on how to move on.

Comment: For 1) have you considered [Electron](https://electronjs.org/)? For 2) No you can't. You need some kind of API layer on top of MongoDB since client-side JS can only call http endpoints.

Answer (score 1):

For the first question: Your user will always be able to see the compiled code (through the developer console for example) but not the source code of the angular application.